QGIS cannot connect to serial "GPS"
I am working on a larger project with the end goal of streaming GPS data via LoRa to a receiver attached to a computer on COM6 and passing the data via a simulated COM4 through a simulated COM5 to QGIS. I can get an NMEA sentence to be passed from COM4 to COM5. I can get GPSBabel to recognize that sentence and output a KML file that accurately shows the location in Google Maps. However, when I attempt to connect QGIS to the "GPS" on COM5, it times out and fails to connect to anything.
I feel like the problem may be in how the data is streamed, and QGIS is getting data, but it is not streamed as expected, so QGIS does not recognize the data.
Any suggestions? Thoughts? Ideas?
